# How should I recover if I accidentally deadlifted 5x5 instead of 1x5?

Tags: weightlifting, deadlifts, stronglifts

I forgot that in the StrongLifts program you only had to deadlift 1x5 and accidentally did 5x5, will this hurt my recovery? Should I skip my next deadlift during my next workout B?

Comment: How much do you weigh, how tall are you, and how much are you deadlifting and squatting?

Comment: I just started the program last monday. Squatted 50 lb and deadlifted 90 lb. I weigh about 175 lb and I'm 5'6.

Comment: Good on you. Keep adding weight and good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Stay the course.

Your deadlifts are not heavy enough to worry. Add however much weight is called for by the program and do deadlifts 1x5 as scheduled.